# Can my USB device be automatically detached and connected with suspend to RAM?

Tags: 20.04, usb, suspend, systemd

My external audio adapter freezes the Xubuntu system when I try to suspend to RAM, so I can not suspend, if I do not physically disconnect the device beforehand. Is there a way to do it by software?

I have posted a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1855678) about the issue more than a year ago..

Comment: Power Management handles Suspend/Hibernate/Resume, and will let you tickle your device going down and coming up.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement

Comment: @waltinator That article has been updated more than a decade ago last time. Are you sure it still can be applied in the time of systemd?

Comment: Try it. `sudo apt install pm-utils;dpkg -L pm-utils`. The lack of updates leads me to infer a lack of need for updates, so it still should work. How do you suppose `systemd` would interact with Suspend/Hibernate/Resume?

Comment: @waltinator Wikipedia tells: "Following its integrated approach, systemd also provides replacements for various daemons and utilities, including the startup shell scripts, pm-utils, inetd, acpid, syslog, watchdog, cron and atd."